# How to add my own shell script to be able to be autocompleted in terminal by Tab

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have bunch of shell script (`.sh`) command created in a folder `~/bin`, I added this path to `.bashrc` so I can execute them wherever I like.

i.e. a sample command to create git feature branch based off remote master branch

```
. git-feature.sh
```

However some of the shell script name can be long so I'd like to have the feature to type a few letter of the shell script name then hit tab then can get autocomplete just like the file in current folder, how can I achieve such goal?

Comment: Try `source $HOME/.bashrc` if you haven't logout after adding $HOME/bin to your $PATH. And check with `echo $PATH` if you made it correct.

Comment: What is the reason you `source` the script with `.` , instead of launching it by just typing its name?

Comment: Yeah if the script is executable and in your PATH and run rather than sourced, then the default command completion should work out of the box - what is the output of `compgen -c git-f` for example?